# how to access source tree in Twisted trial tests?

Tags: python, twisted, trial

In my trial test case, I want to run scripts from my source tree. Trial changes the working directory, so simple relative paths don't work. In practice, Trial's temporary directory is inside the source tree, but assuming that to be the case seems suboptimal. I.e., I could do:

```
def source_file(p):
    return os.path.join('..', p)
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: more details about your folder strucutre and trial command line arguments would help. Is your code in a package or you only use modules?

Comment: There are multiple packages in this repository. I run trial both over entire packages and on individual test modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find a file next to your test and run it as a script, you can just do this:

```
from twisted.python.modules import getModule
script = getModule(__name__).filePath.path
# ...
reactor.spawnProcess(..., script, ...)
```

You can also use this to support storing your code in a zip file, although invoking it with Python becomes a little more difficult that way.  Have you considered just using `python -m`?

Comment: The script is not a Python script. One could also imagine wanting to get the path of some test data contained in a file in the source directory.

Comment: At any rate, your suggestion works well if I invoke trial on the package in question, or if I invoke it with the filename of the test from outside the package. If I invoke trial from the package subdirectory, I get a `UserWarning: test (for module test_chunkpost) not in path importer cache (PEP 302 violation - check your local configuration).` But I can live with that.

Comment: Yes, this means that your Python interpreter has a somewhat inconsistent view of its own import path; `sys.path` has an entry on it that points somewhere inside another entry.  Don't do that :).